How to *really* suppress the IMEKeyboard in JetpackCompose
I have a functioning "old school" Android app that I am trying to convert to use Jetpack-Compose.
One thing I had working perfectly before was suppressing the appearance of the IME Keyboard for a particular EditText view. Now I want to do the same thing with a TextField under Jetpack-Compose.
Requirements are actually quite simple:

No IME Keyboard ever (there is a physical keyboard requirement -- long story)
A single TextField that never ever loses focus.
Each time Text is entered, the appropriate event is kicked off to add the entered text into an List<String> in a ViewModel (which would cause its own series of things to happen on the screen -- Previously accomplished with a RecyclerView and an Adapter), the text in the Entry is then cleared, and the Entry waits for more input.

This StackOverflow Question seems come the closest to addressing my issue, but its atrophied with the multiple methods of doing this seemingly becoming deprecated, and none have actually worked (or aren't on point as a read-only field won't work in this case).
Previously, hiding the IME keyboard was this simple:
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



This seems to be the answer
After setting your theme, but before calling the first Composable method:
    val imm = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus?.windowToken, 0)


https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/touch-input/keyboard-input/commands
Try the link above. Below is an excerp.
 "When the user gives focus to an editable text component, such as a TextField, and the device has a hardware keyboard attached, all input is handled by the system. You can provide keyboard shortcuts by handling key events.

Note: Key events can be handled by implementing the KeyEvent.Callback interface on an Activity class. Refer to Handle keyboard actions in views for details."

Not sufficient. its the source of the KeyEvents I'm trying to dictate, not what happens after them
